# How to extend data recursively with jQuery.data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a better way to do this:

```
var extended = $.extend(entity.data('namespace'), {
    att1    : whatever,
    att2    : whatever
});
entity.data('namespace', extended);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is recursive about this?

Comment: I'm using the terminology from the jQuery.extend() documentation (see here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/). "Recursive" here refers to extending nested objects (the highest level object in this case being `{ namespace : { att1 : val, att2 : val } }` ).

Comment: `extend` is only recursive if its first argument is `true`, which isn't the case in your snippet, which in turn makes your question rather confusing...

Comment: I'd also say make up a simpler example. There seems to be too many datas and vals here, and entity is what exactly? And where does jQuery.data come in?

Comment: @Amadan: if you're using the jQuery.data with an `object` for an argument, the object is extended by default. However, it is not extended recursively. What I need is a way to for it be extended recursively. Hence the question title.

Comment: @boyetboy `entity` is the jQuery object on which the `data` method is being called. That seems as good a name as any to me. Good call on the variable names, I edited for clarity. The `data` method is called on the first and last lines of code.

Comment: To me, "better way to do this" means another, possibly shorter or faster, way to do the exactly same thing. If you want the recursive `extend`, do as the docs that you linked say, put `true` as the first argument: `entity.data('namespace', $.extend(true, entity.data('namespace'), { ... })`

Comment: @Amadan What I was hoping was that there was a way to make the `data` method fire the jQuery.extend method recursively. It doesn't seem to be so. Yours is the best answer; if you want to submit it as such, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.data()` doesn't know how to extend. If you want to extend, you have to do it yourself with jquery's `.extend()` method. Recursive extension can be achieved by placing `true` as the first parameter, so:

```
entity.data('namespace', $.extend(true, entity.data('namespace'), { ... }));
```

Comment: This indeed seems to be the case. The jquery documentation is confusing on this point because it reads `In jQuery 1.4.3 setting an element's data object with .data(obj) extends the data previously stored with that element.`

Comment: jQuery's extend will modify the first object, so you can just do $.extend(true, $(el).data('namespace'), {new: 'stuff}). @chrishiestand, I agree the documentation is confusing. I think it means that additional data keys are extended, allowing you to set $(el).data('a', 1) then $(el).data('b', 2) without removing a.